# React click counter incrementing by 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A little confused here: A simple click counter yet instead of incrementing by 1, it increments by 2.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const myComponentDiv = useRef(null)
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);


  const clickHandler = () => {
    setClickCount(clickCount +1)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    myComponentDiv.current.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    return () => {
    myComponentDiv.current.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    }
  }, [clickCount]);

  return (
    <div className="my-component" ref={myComponentDiv}>
      <h2 onClick={clickHandler}>
        My Component ({clickCount} clicks)
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Because you bound the click handler twice: once through the `onClick` prop and then another time in a react useEffect hook. There is no need to bind the click event listener in the hook at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding two click event listeners, one on the h2 and one on the div. If you click on the h2, the click bubbles/propagates up to trigger both. You should not be manually `addEventListener` with React, that's what `onClick` is for.

You code should look like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setClickCount((currentClickCount) => currentClickCount + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="my-component">
      <h2 onClick={clickHandler}>
        My Component ({clickCount} clicks)
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default MyComponent;
```